# reading a csv with python and handling blanks

Tags: python

i am reading a csv file line by line here:

```
def GetDistinctValues(theFile, theColumn):
  lines=theFile.split('\n')
  allValues=[]
  for line in lines:
    if line:
        distinctValue=line.split(',')[theColumn]
        allValues.append(distinctValue)        
  return list(set(allValues))
```

here is what my csv looks like:

```
1,hat,dog
2,,cat
3,pants,elephant
4,,,
```

as you can see, sometimes there are blanks.

in the above code i am trying to get all the unique values in a specific column, but this does not work since the column shifts sometimes because it does not account for blanks.

how can account for all the blanks and get all distinct values from a specific column?

Comment: Have you heard of this? http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu looks great! how would i get distinct values from a column using that?

Comment: @Артём Царионов See the examples section: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples You can access the row using a the `[]` operator

Comment: What's the problem of your code? Why you think columns will shift? Eg, for `theColumn = 2`; it'll return `['dog', 'cat', 'elephant', '']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
import csv

def get_distinct_values(filename, column):
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        return set(line[column] for line in reader)
```

which gives

```
>>> get_distinct_values("ccol.csv", 0)
set(['1', '3', '2', '4'])
>>> get_distinct_values("ccol.csv", 1)
set(['', 'hat', 'pants'])
>>> get_distinct_values("ccol.csv", 2)
set(['', 'elephant', 'dog', 'cat'])
```

You could use `set(line[column] for line in reader if line[column])` or something if you wanted to get rid of the empty values.

Comment: with open(theFile, "rb") as fp:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _csv.reader found

Comment: When using `with open(something)`, the "something" should usually be a filename.  Your error message makes it seem like you passed it something else, a csv.reader.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started:

```
import csv
csvf=csv.reader(open(yourfile,'rb'))

col=0
rtr=set()
for row in csvf:
    rtr.add(row[col])

print rtr
```

On your example, prints:

```
set(['1', '3', '2', '4'])
```